# Double slit experiment - what is the amplitude of the interfering waves?

Tags: double-slit-experiment, wave-particle-duality

I would like to consider a situation in which we fire single particles, one after another.

If I understand correctly asking about the amplitude does not necessarily make sense. Unless I am wrong, the question is simply: what is the amplitude of the interfering waves?

Instead I would like to ask what happens here:

[image]

Black triangles are the particle guns, orange brackets are detectors.

In this case we see no interference on the upper detector and we do see an interference on the lower detector. Is that correct?

But what happens now:

[image]

Should I expect the upper detector to show interference exactly the same as the one on the lower detector in the previous example? Will the lower detector show no interference with 50% particle density of the upper detector from the previous example?

Comment: ghurpost, your statement that "In this case we see no interference on the upper detector" isn't right. See about [Fraunhoffer diffraction](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fraunhofer_diffraction) and please note that behind everey (sharp) edge an intensity distribution of the light takes place.

Comment: @HolgerFiedler: from Wiki about double slit experiment:  "in top image, one slit is closed. In the single-slit image, a diffraction pattern (the faint spots on either side of the main band) forms due to the nonzero width of the slit. A diffraction pattern is also seen in the double-slit image, but at twice the intensity and with the addition of many smaller interference fringes." I'm not saying there will be no diffraction - I am referring to interference. Or am I missing something? Plus I do not require the experiment to be performed with photons (tho I think there is particle diffraction).

Answer (score -1):

Yes, your interpretation of the first example is correct.

In the second example, you should not see interference anywhere. The lower detector sees only one hole, hence no interference. Although the upper detector sees two holes, they are fed by different guns. Hence, again no interference.

To see interference one must have the situation where one and the same particle can go through two holes and then meet again on the detector. So, there must be two paths, starting from the same source going through different holes reaching the same point on the detector.

Comment: I don't think your answer is correct. Because if that experiment were done with photons (with phase coherence) in spite of being created from 2 different sources, they will certainly interfere with each other! So I don't think there should be a difference between them qualitatively (particle vs photons). (However I am not a physicist. Please, help from a pro is required here :-))

Comment: The assumption is that the two separate sources are mutually incoherent, otherwise, what would be the point of showing two separate sources? Of course, if they are mutually coherent they would interfere, but then why not show it is one source?